# layout support different screen size & different platform version

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I have:

```
layout/
layout-v7/
```

directory, which holds the layout files for **Android 2.1 API 7** platform. It works fine with my app. My app loads layout from `layout-v7/` when run on Android 2.1 platform.

Then, I decide to support **API 7** on **large** screen and **small** screen respectively, so I make the following layout directories:

```
layout/
layout-small-v7/
layout-large-v7/
```

I run my app on small screen Android 2.1 API 7 platform, but I got **error:**

**Activity has leaked window**

Why?

Comment: check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added

Answer (score 0):

Try insert this in **Manifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|navigation"
```